# PHP - How can a load page do some of the php

Tags: php

I wish every time I reload or refresh the page. The disabled `textbox` still `disabled`. Because my purpose is to modify the `textbox` once time and then it will be `disabled` forever. Is this possible?

Below is my code

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $lang_txt['leader_id'][$lang]; ?></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><?php if($_POST['txtLeaderID'] == ""){?><input type="text"  name="txtLeaderID" id="txtLeaderID" style="width:400px;" value="<?php echo $merchant['LeaderID']; ?>" maxlength="20" /><?php }
    else
    {
    ?>
        <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="txtLeaderID" id="txtLeaderID" style="width:400px;" value="<?php echo $merchant['LeaderID']; ?>" maxlength="20" /><?php
    }
    ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please clarify your requirements.

Comment: @ManishJ how clarify?

Comment: Using either a `Session` or `Cookie` will allow you to save the state of the text box - if you need it to be secure I recommend using a `Session`...

Comment: @pc-shooter u mean use session at the beginning of the page ??

Comment: I mean, read about sessions in php: https://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Comment: Use session cookie or local storage. A cookie will allow you to persist the settings over multiple sessions but is less secure, whereas a session will save those changes for the duration of that session

Answer (score 0):

Your variant will be worked with

```
    if(!$_POST['txtLeaderID']){echo('<input type="text"  name="txtLeaderID" id="txtLeaderID" style="width:400px;" value="'.$merchant['LeaderID'].'" maxlength="20" />')} else {echo('<input type="text"  disabled="disabled" name="txtLeaderID" id="txtLeaderID" style="width:400px;" value="'.$merchant['LeaderID'].'" maxlength="20" />')}
```

For example:

```
<?php

if (!$_POST['username']){
echo('
<form action="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'" method="post">
    Name:  <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
    Email : <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send POST!" />
</form>
');} 
else{
echo('
<form>
    Name:  <input type="text" name="username" disabled="disabled"/><br />
    Email : <input type="text" name="email" disabled="disabled"/><br />

</form>
');} 

?>
```

But it didn't work, if we open it in a new tab. You must save this propery anywhere ([session](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php), [cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php), sql)and check the stored values. it will be work in a new tab.

For example with session:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['data'])) {
    $_SESSION['data'] = true;

echo('
<form action="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'" method="post">
    Name:  <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
    Email : <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send POST!" />
</form>
');} 
else{
echo('
<form>
    Name:  <input type="text" name="username" disabled="disabled"/><br />
    Email : <input type="text" name="email" disabled="disabled"/><br />

</form>
');} 

?>
```